How to re-mmap a SHM onto a new file keeping memory data?
I created a SHM file in /dev/shm, and mmapped it to a block of memory in a long time working daemon program.
There are many such workers(processes), and they all will create many such shm files(about thousands).
I want to shm_unlink the files after my app initialized, and remap them later,
because these shm files are required only when my app starting and exiting(inter-process validating data).
But when I remmap it at second time, I got a different address, even though I passed the old address to mmap(). Further more, I guess that the shm created later can NOT include the old data, without a manually copy.
Is there a way, I can re-mmap a block of memory onto a new shm file, and reserve the data in the memory?
My codes like this:
constexpr int    NUMBS = 64;
constexpr auto   BYTES = NUMBS * sizeof( int64_t );
constexpr char   shm_name[] = "remap-shm";

// when initializing my app
auto shm_file = shm_open( shm_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
ftruncate( shm_file, BYTES );
auto old_addr = mmap( NULL, BYTES, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE, shm_file, 0 );
close( shm_file );
shm_unlink( shm_name );

// now my app is working, has writed much data into the SHM
auto work_buf = reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>( old_addr );
for( int j = 0; j < NUMBS; ++j )
    work_buf[j] = j;

// at the end, it need to recreate the shm file, with reserving the data
shm_file = shm_open( shm_name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );
ftruncate( shm_file, BYTES );
auto new_addr = mmap( old_addr, BYTES, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE, shm_file, 0 );
if( new_addr != old_addr ) {
    std::cerr << "It mapped to another address!" << std::endl;
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// check if the data still exists
bool all_eq = true;
for( int j = 0; j < NUMBS; ++j )
    all_eq = all_eq && ( work_buf[j] == j );

if( all_eq ) {
    std::cout << "The data survived." << std::endl;
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
} else {
    std::cerr << "The data has been cleared." << std::endl;
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}


If you want to replace the old mapping with one to the newly created shm file, you have to set the MAP_FIXED flag in the second mmap call. But I don't get the rest of your logic. You don't unmap the original mapping so it is still there. Creating a new file and mapping it over the old mapping will naturally delete the old data. Do you instead want to transfer the old data to a new shm file which you then map over the original? Then don't ftruncate, instead write the old data to the new file descriptor before mapping

Yes, my purpose is to let other processes created after shm_unlink can share the data through a new mapping, meanwhile keep the old data,  without copying a lot of data.

If I write the whole contents into the file before the second mmap, I think that indeed is a memory copy? isn't it?

You can't resurrect a deleted file in a portable manner. You can only create a new one and fill it with the same data. Or you keep the old file around. There is a linux-specific way but it's not working for me. Depending on the use case you can also just keep the file descriptor around and send it via a socket to other processes
